# Is it possible to block a certain email adress from sending email anywhere other to its own domain?

Tags: email, postfix, domain, block

I wonder if its possible to block all but few specific adresses to send outgoing emails anywhere other than its own domain. Also so they could still recive incomming messages.
Blocking everyone isnt that hard from what i can see but blocking just few specific users is a whole different story it would seem.

Comment: Well it depends entirely on your mail server; and that will make the difference between how easy/hard it will be :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's entirely possible with postfix [Restriction Classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html#external), you can group users in a table, and then apply certain access patterns (can only send to certain domains, can't send at all, etc).

A simple example would be under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` you add a line to check the sender access: `check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access`

in the file `sender_access` you put the email address, and the policy applied (it's better to whitelist, since you say a few users, so specifically allow them to send anywhere, then the others add a larger group.. just the domain for example).

*/etc/postfix/sender_access*:

```
user1@yourdomain.com      all
user2@yourdomain.com      all
@yourdomain.com           local
```

Then you need to define those classes.

```
smtpd_restriction_classes = local, all

local = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/local_dom, reject
all = check_recipient_access regex:/etc/postfix/all_dom, reject
```

*/etc/postfix/local*:

```
domain1.com    OK
domain2.com    OO
```

*/etc/postfix/all*:

```
^*@*  OK
```

This isn't perfect (my regex *should* work), as mail from names are not restricted, and of course, your mail users could also send through another server, but this is one basic way of doing what you ask. You can also substitute the hash tables for SQL, etc..